# Data Binding Split Button List jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, list, data-binding, jquery-mobile, split-button

I am creating a split button list in jQuery mobile using the following [tutorial](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-split.html) as a guide. I need to bind data and a handler to each button (within a given list element). Below I have outlined three approaches, none of which seem to work. Can any one advise me on how to bind data for a split button list?

```
function createSingleList(dataArray) {
var i;
var list = $("<ul></ul>");
for (i = 0; i <= singleArray.length - 1; i = i + 1) {
    var button1 = $('<div><a id="button1" href="">Button 1</a><div>');
    var button2 = $('<div><a id="button2" href="">Button 2</a><div>');

    //Approach 1
    button1.data("data", dataArray[i])
    button2.data("data", dataArray[i])

    //Approach 2
    $("#button1").bind("click", {
        data: dataArray[i]
    }, clickHandler1);

    $("#button2").bind("click", {
        data: dataArray[i]
    }, clickHandler2);

    //Approach 3
    $("#button1").on("click", {
        data: dataArray[i]
    }, clickHandler1);

    $("#button2").on("click", {
        data: dataArray[i]
    }, clickHandler2);

    var listElement = $('<li></li>').html($(button1.html() + button2.html()));

    list.append(listElement);
   }
}

function clickHandler1(e) {
   alert(e.data);
}

function clickHandler2(e) {
   alert(e.data);
}
```

Comment: <ul data-split-icon='some_icon'></ul>         <li><a href='#' onclick='clickHandler1(urs_data)'></a>Button 1<a href='#' onclick='clickHandler2(urs_data)'></a>Button 2 </li>

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm a little confused about the implementation of urs_data? Would you be willing to extrapolate a little? Particularly how does this code fit in the for loop and how is the array data getting associated with urs_data?

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = $('<ul data-split-icon="some_icon"></ul>');
```

var html = '';
for (i = 0; i <= singleArray.length - 1; i++) {

```
var param1 = "'"+ dataArray[i] +"'";
html += '<li><a href="#" onclick="clickHandler1('+param1+')"></a>Button 1<a href="#" onclick="clickHandler2('+param1+')"></a>Button 2 </li>';
```

}

list.append($(html));

```
$('<ul>').trigger('create');
```

And

```
function clickHandler1(e){
```

alert(e);

}